# Number of ways of choosing courses

Tags: combinatorics

An economics student must choose 4 courses to attend in the forthcoming academic year. There are 8 courses offered by different lecturers. Prof. V. Lowmark: Microeconomics,Macroeconomics and Game theory. Prof. A. Greedman: Banking and Stock markets. Dr. T. Kantan: Asian economics. Dr. U. Workmore:Developing countries and Labor economics.

Prof. Lowmark is the head of the department, so the student thinks it may be a good idea to take his course. However, his exams are very difficult, so the student does not want to take more than one of his courses. Given this, in how many ways can he choose the courses?

Comment: One thing for sure: each and everyone of these professors would expect you to do your homework on your own, and not post it here and get others doing it for you!

Comment: I don't ask anyone to do my homework for me, I just want someone to give me a hint

Comment: Well, you're generally expected to show what effort you've made in attempting to solve the problem on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**  The student wishes to take four of the eight available economics courses.  Since Professor Lowmark offers three of them and the student wishes to take exactly one course from Professor Lowmark, the student must choose one of the three courses offered by Professor Lowmark and three of the five courses offered by the other professors in the economics department.

Comment: Is the answer 180?

Comment: We have 3 choices for the first course, then 5 choices for the second one, 4 choices for the third one and 3 choices for the last one. I just multiplied 3,5,4 and 3 and got 180. Is it right?

Comment: Not quite.  We do have three choices for Professor Lowmark's course.  Note that the order in which the student selects the other three courses does not matter.  Therefore, you want a combination rather than a permutation of three of the other five courses.

Comment: so, there are 10 ways to choose three of the five courses

Comment: And there are 3 choices for the first course, so we just multiply 3 by 10 and get 30? Am I right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: May I ask one more question connected with this one?

Comment: The probability of choosing Dr. Kantan's course is 1/2 as the sudent can either choose it or not. Is it correct?

Comment: I am assuming that the student is still choosing four courses.  If Dr. Kantan's course is selected, then three of the other seven courses must also be selected.  Therefore, the number of course selections that include Dr. Kantan's course is $$\binom{1}{1}\binom{7}{3}$$  The total number of ways four of the eight courses can be selected is $$\binom{8}{4}$$  Hence, the probability that Dr. Kantan's course is selected is $$\frac{\dbinom{1}{1}\dbinom{7}{3}}{\dbinom{8}{4}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since the constraint is only on choosing Professor Lowmarks courses...the student can select any one of his course in 3 ways.....Now he has to select 3 more courses out of the 5 which are available ie not taught by Professor Lowmark and since according to me there are no constraints on the selection of the other 3 courses the student can select three courses from the remaining five in (5 C 3) ways ie 10 ways.....therefore total no.  of ways of selecting the courses would be 10×3=30.

Comment: While your strategy is correct, there are only five courses that Professor Lowmark does not teach since Professor Lowmark teaches three courses and there are a total of eight courses.

Comment: Aah!!..thanks for pointing out the mistake...i misinterpreted the question...